# Cypress and cookies popup: how to get rid of it

Tags: javascript, local-storage, cypress

I am testing a website with Cypress; this website has the classic popup to accept cookies in the bottom part of the page.
Since i'm testing a part of the website where there are a form with multiple steps (a page with some data, button next, another page, etc.), my issue is that every single time this cookie popup appears again for every page.

I think it's something about saving data in `localStorage`, but I'm not sure how to manage it. I tried just putting `cy.saveLocalStorage()` after the `cy.get('a#cookiePopup').click()` , but it says that `cy.localStorage is not a function`.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved: I found [this](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies#Preserve-Once) that explains how to put `cy.preserveOnce('<name-of-your-cookie>')` in the `beforeEach` loop at start.

I'm putting this here for future reference.

Comment: now it's cy.session https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session but imho it's easier simply to push specific cookie by `cy.setCookie('cookiebar_cookie_name', 'some_value_with_cookies_enabled_or_disabled')`

Comment: good point, cypress evolves fast